# How can I detect Shopify activated theme name?

Tags: shopify

I have look for Shopify theme detector but I have no idea how it works and how to detect WordPress activated theme into theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can access theme related info via the `theme` object

```
{{ theme.id }} - The ID of current active theme
{{ theme.name }} - The name of current active theme
```

This is a very nice cheat sheet you should be using: https://www.shopify.com/partners/shopify-cheat-sheet